# C++ Temperature Converting

Tags: c++

I have this problem in my `while` loop. The program reads the quit (-999) line after reading Fahrenheit temperature. In the beginning I didn't have this problem until I was trying to make it print the correct answer for Average and I ruined everything.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
void main() 
{
    float fahr =0 , cent = 0, fsum = 0, csum = 0;
    float favg = 0;
    float cavg = 0;
    int temp_cnt = 0;
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("temps.dat");
    fout << setw(25) << "fahrenheit" << setw(20) << "centigrade" << endl;
    fout.setf(ios::fixed);
    fout.setf(ios::showpoint);
    fout.precision(1);
    while (fahr != -999)
    {

         cout << "Enter a fahrenheit temperature enter. -999 toquit"<< endl;
    temp_cnt++;
    cin >> fahr;
    fsum += fahr;
    csum += cent;

    cent = float((5.0 / 9.0))*float((fahr - 32));
    fout << setw(25) << fahr << setw(20) << cent << endl;
    csum = csum + cent;
}

fout << endl;
fout << setw(15) << "Average:";
favg =float ((fsum / temp_cnt));
cavg = float ((csum / temp_cnt));
fout << setw(10) << favg << setw(20) << cavg << endl;
return ;
}
```

And the output in temp.dat file:

```
           fahrenheit          centigrade
                 86.0                30.0
                 91.0                32.8
                 87.4                30.8
                100.3                37.9
                 98.6                37.0
                 77.0                25.0
                 83.7                28.7
               -999.0              -572.8

   Average:     -46.9               -16.0
```

Comment: What do you see when debugging it?

Comment: You have to put a break or condition after you read input.

Comment: You sum celsius twice, so the celsius average is wrong, you do it in csum += cent; and then on csum = csum + cent;

Answer (score 0):

After the line:

```
cin >> fahr;
```

Add:

```
if(fahr==-999)
    break;
```

Hope this helps. Good luck!