# Google Search Images algorithm - how does it work?

Tags: algorithm, search

So, i'm googling someone (a person's name) by images and I get lots if images as a result, besides the person im searching for. I get lots of other peoples pics who are related through google+ (for example), but other connections of the same person on the same google+ wouldnt show up.

Can anyone explain how does the google image search algorithm works? What elements takes into account to generate the results?

Answer (score 2):

As [Googleblog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39458879/c-temperature-converting/39693827#39693827) states,

> The technology behind Search by Image analyzes your image to find its most distinctive points, lines and textures and creates a mathematical model. We match that model against billions of images in our index, and page analysis helps us derive a best guess text description of your image. Search by Image technology also includes the ability to match against images on the web so that we can show you similar images and webpages that contain your image.

When Google first introduced Search By Image, they emphasized that it does not use facial recognition. Although Google's Picasa photo service does facial recognition and others like [Exalead](https://www.exalead.com/search/) do, too, it's become an issue on the privacy front. Even Facebook provides facial recognition to identify friends in newly uploaded photos. But due to privacy concerns, Google has gone to great lengths to deny any plans of using this technology.